# jQuery: Make submenu appear and disappear after a period of time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a submenu which appears after some time. If it's already open I'd like other menus to pop up instantly on hover. However, on mouse leave it should stay open for a short time because the user could have moved the mouse accidentally outside the child-div.

Well, the problem is that it even opens (after the set time) if you hover it accidentally. This shouldn't happen.

Here's my code:

```
var timer = false;
$('li.mega-menu-dropdown').hover(function(e){
    var el = this;

    if ($("li.mega-menu-dropdown.open").length == 0)
    {                     
        setTimeout(function() {
            openMenu(el);
        }, 1000); 
    } else {
        clearTimeout(timer);  
        openMenu(el);
    }
},
function(){ 
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        $('li.mega-menu-dropdown').removeClass('open');   
    },300);
});

function openMenu(el) {
    $('li.mega-menu-dropdown').removeClass('open');
    $(el).toggleClass("open");  
}
```

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bsnubner/

**Edit:**

Just hover it, stay there with the mouse and it'll work as expected. But then try to move the mouse over the "Hover Menu"-Link and instantly away of it. You'll see that it automatically opens the submenu even if you aren't in the menu anymore. Even worse: You have to go inside and outside the menu again to close it.

The problem will be, that on hover it sets the timeout with the function call. This will execute the function after the set time - even if you aren't in the menu anymore. But how could I prevent it?

I'd be very thankful if you could lead me on the right track.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle with the actual code running?

Comment: Thank you! I've added the fiddle and some additional info :)

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are trying to accomplish, just show the submenu when you hover over 'hover menu'?

Comment: Hi, first I want to say that I solved it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bsnubner/3/ even if I'm not sure if it's the best solution. I wanted the submenu to show up in a certain time. But if I only hover a short time over it and then went out of the menu, I wanted it to remain hidden. The second thing is, that if there are more items and a menu is already opened, the second link should open his submenu instantly on hover: http://jsfiddle.net/bsnubner/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, my solution is as follows if you haven't a better one:

I have simply added:

```
var startTimer = false;
```

And kill the timer if the user accidentally hovered a menu link.

http://www.jsfiddle.net/bsnubner/4

If a user hovers "Hover Menu" it'll pop up after the timeout. If he then hovers "Hover Menu 2" and the other submenu is still opened, it'll open the second submenu instantly without delay.
If the user accidentally hovers one menu link only for a short time it won't open it's submenu. 
Onmouseleave it closes as expected after some time :)